# Constraint bug in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, constraints

I have a view that it has 4 constraint:

[image]

it works fine but when I change view as in storyboard to another device (e.g Iphone 4s) but I build for Iphone 6 it changes to this:
[image]
[image]

and the weird part is when I change the view as to Iphone6 it works fine:

this screen shot is when I change my storyboard view as to iphone 6

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the frame of your `UIView` in your `viewDidLoad()` method as

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 70, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-70)
```

70 is a static value of your header placed above your view that you can change according to your view.